# Syncing new folders created on server with Git

Tags: git, github

I have an application on a server that is going to be creating new folders.  Though the environment itself uses Git as it's repository.  What is the best way for me to commit those folders and push them to the git repository so the server and the coders are not out of sync?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script that runs a git add and push on file creation. I believe there are some free to use scripts that do just that if you google them too. I would include a link to one but as I don't know how your app will be creating them, I can't suggest one for your use case.